# Get filename without path and extension using in cmd prompt

Tags: cmd, path, filenames, file-extension, subdirectory

I have a folder with subfolders and files.

I want filenames inside this folder without path and extension.

I don't want any filenames inside the subfolders (no recursivity).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for /f "tokens=*" %i in ('dir /b /a-d') do echo %~ni
```

to use it in a batchfile, double the percent-signs:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('dir /b /a-d') do echo %%~ni
```

Comment: when tried to make txt file using > f.txt ,  it only gives last filename.

Comment: just adding `>f.txt` would overwrite the file, resulting in the file containing the last name only. Either use `>>f.txt` (append) or enclose the command in parantheses: `(for /f .... do echo %%~ni ) >f.txt` to get the complete list.

Answer (score 1):

In Powershell, that would be like this:

`ls -file | % { $_.basename }`

If you want to run this from a cmd shell, you can do this:

`powershell.exe -command { ls -file | % { $_.basename } }`

Powershell rocks for things like this, so unless you really have to use plain old CMD.exe, I'd suggest using this.

Comment: oh thanks. but i don't know how  to use powershell. i got the answer for using it in cmd.

Comment: check it out though if you have the time, it'll make your scripting life a lot easier :)